# Proving that $(1_V-iT)$ is bijective when $\langle T(v),w\rangle=\langle v,T(w)\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, inner-products

Given that, on an arbitrary vector space $V$ over a field $K$ (where $K$ is either the real or the complex numbers) with inner product, the linear operator $T$ is such that $\langle T(v),w\rangle= \langle v,T(w)\rangle$, we must be able to prove that the linear operator on $V$ given by $(1_V-iT)$ is bijective.

Honestly, I have very little idea how to prove this. I would like to think that by proving injectivity, since the operator is linear then we also have surjectivity.
I do not know, however, how the hypothesis for the product comes in.

Also, maybe if $T$ is bijective, then the other operator must also be bijective.

Comment: What does $1_V - iT$ mean if $K = \Bbb R$, i.e., if $V$ is a *real* vector space?

Comment: Well $(1_V - iT)(x) = (1_V(x)-iT(x) = x - iT(x)$. (assigns $x$ to $x-iT(x)$)

Comment: Yes, but what does $iT(x)$ *mean* if $T(x)$ is in a *real* vector space $V$?  Do you wish to sort of automatically move to its *complexification*  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification)?  I'm trying to answer your question, and if I finish, I will have addressed the issue, but I'd like to read your take on it.  By the way, thanks for responding, and rapidly at that . . .

Comment: So $iT(x)$ when $T(x)$ is in a real vector space, explicitly means multiplying $i$ times the $T(x)$. It "turns" it into a complex number. I guess there's something here which I'm *meant* to be seeing

Comment: The wikipedia page I cited is helpful . . .

Comment: Ok, so I don't think I've quite yet grasped it fully. But, $x-iT(x)$ would be a vector in a space over the complex field. With $iT(x)$ being the "imaginary part".

Comment: Yeah, that's going in the right direction . . .

Comment: I added the "functional analysis" tag to your post.  Cheers!